# SCP not working when sending files from remote to local

Tags: scp

I'm trying to send some files from a remote server to my local computer. Here's the command I'm using on the remote server that doesn't work:

```
scp name@123.123.123.123:~/path/to/file.name C:\Users\Desktop\Name\file\
```

This didn't work, and so I tried this one as well (which also didn't work)

```
scp name@123.123.123.123:~/path/to/file.name name2@132.132.132.132:~/Desktop/dir
```

I got `name2` by typing the `hostname` command in my local Windows command prompt.

Also, when I say "doesn't work" I mean that on the remote server, the terminal doesn't return anything and sort of freezes until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or something like that.

What might be the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "local computer" running Ubuntu? Windows? WSL? Something else?

Comment: As you work on Windows OS to copy files from remote host securly use WinSCP (https://winscp.net). To be able to send files directly from remote server to your desktop initiating this process on server side you must have public IP and correctly setup port forwarding on your router.

Comment: `I got name2 by typing the hostname command in my local Windows command prompt.`: you need your user name, not the machine's hostname.